# How to store the output of a print(subprocess.checkout) to a variable in Python?

Tags: python, bash

I have the below print statement

```
print(subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', shell_script], stdin=open('/etc/fstab', 'r')))
```

that prints few lines like '/xyz NOT mounted' and I would like to store it into a variable just like how the lambda function does it.

```
out = lambda: print("/xyz NOT mounted")
out()
```

I would then need to use that variable to write an if statement as in 
if out contains any string, then print contains string, else contains nothing

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, tested and written in Python2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
out="/xyz NOT mounted"
if re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+', out):
    print "String found."
else:
    print "String NOT found."
```

When value of variable out is having string values it prints `String found.`

---

---

Now lets test it with NULL value of variable val here.

```
cat script.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
out=""
if re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+', out):
    print "String found."
else:
    print "String NOT found."
```

When we run above then it gives as `String NOT found.`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot run your code on my machine because I miss the shell_script part.

For similar cases I use subprocess.PIPE and collect the output lines in a list that you can iterate and check later:

```
import subprocess

def bash_command(cmd):
    sp = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return sp.stdout.readlines()

result = bash_command('ls') # Insert here your bash command

for line in result:
    if "NOT mounted" in line:
        print("Hey I have a line containing NOT mounted")
    else:
        print("Hey I have a line not containing NOT mounted")
```

Comment: I like your code, My first test resulted in an error, I will run again and let you know

Comment: Which error did you get? Please provide more details about your input, I'd be glad to help. If you found my code useful please don't forget to upvote and / or choose it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

can you not just save the variable and then print it?

```
 x = subprocess.check_output()
 print(x)

 #and then...
 if x == ???:
    #do something
```

Saving the variable and printing it seems a lot easier than trying to grab hold of the print statements' output.

Comment: subprocess.check_output(), as is, will return a string. For this reason it will be hard to tell which lines contain the desired output and which lines not simply iterating the string character by character.

Answer (score 0):

Here, an example to execute a command using subprocess and store and output/buffer data in a variable.

Ex:

```
Command_Input = subprocess.Popen("Your Command",stdin=process_output.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
Command_Output = Command_Input.communicate()[0]
Print(Command_Output)
```